# Collapsable Table with Sortable, Moving 2 Rows at Once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to mix two jquery events together and am having a hard time getting it to work correctly. I am using JQuery UI's sortable function, to allow drag and dropping of table rows... and using a Jquery collapsible menu. Basically when you click the parent row, a child opens underneath it.

I need to be able to drag the parent, and have the child row follow along. Clicking the parent should have the child appear below the parent. Currently the child is left behind and expands where the parent used to be.

Also the child should not be able to be sortable.

I have a JSFiddle showing this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/u7cfZ/

Here is the HTML:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parent" id="parent-1"><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr class="child-parent-1"><td>1.1</td></tr>
        <tr class="parent" id="parent-2"><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr class="child-parent-2"><td>2.1</td></tr>
        <tr class="parent" id="parent-3"><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr class="child-parent-3"><td>3.1</td></tr>
        <tr class="parent" id="parent-4"><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr class="child-parent-4"><td>4.1</td></tr>
        <tr class="parent" id="parent-5"><td>5</td></tr>
        <tr class="child-parent-5"><td>5.1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JQuery:

```
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor","pointer")
    .attr("title","Click to expand/collapse")
    .click(function(){
        $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        $('tr[class^=child-]').not('.child-'+this.id).hide();
});

$('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('td');

$('table tbody').sortable({
    helper: function(e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function() {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    },
    cursor: 'move',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'URL_HERE'
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

I'm trying to keep is clean, and since the tables will contain data.. I'm trying to maintain using HTML tables vs DIV / UL / LI.

Can anyone help come up with a solution that moves the child along with the parent?

Comment: There is one plugin for nested sortable http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/ but I am afraid that it works only for lists and not for tables !

Comment: I've seen nested tables, but as you mention it is not capable of being used on table rows with structured data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution. The answer seems to be to add a function to sortable that is triggered upon 'start' and 'stop'. The code I am using is this:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.item.startPos < ui.item.index()){
        var child = $('.child-' + ui.item.context.id).remove().clone();
        $('#' + ui.item.context.id).after(child);
        var child = $('.'+$('.child-' + ui.item.context.id).next().attr('class')).remove().clone();
        $('#' + ui.item.context.id).before(child);    
    }else{
        var child = $('.child-' + ui.item.context.id).remove().clone();
        $('#' + ui.item.context.id).after(child);
    }
},
```

The child row is copied into a variable and then removed. It is placed into the code after the parent row.

There is a jsfiddle showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/u7cfZ/14/

There was a bug that caused the row to cut off a different child row when moving down, so there are two separate functions that are triggered depending on which direction the move is going.